# Bootstrap modal not loading after ajax form submit

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-5, bootstrap-modal

Having a weird issue with MVC and Bootstrap Modals with remote content.

Im currently using Bootstrap v3.3.5 and MVC 5.

The modals fire up fine and load in the remote content as expected when using the link on the partial view on the initial page load so i know the modals do work.

The edge case is that parts of my Razor View have Prtial Views with MVC Ajax Forms that when submitted replace original html with the re-rendered Partial View and once this has happened the BootStrap modals wont load the remote content when the link is clicked. The modal renders (i see the black overlay) however no content is loaded.

If i look at the network traffic there is no GET request to load up the remote content for the modal.

My **_Layout.cshtml** contains this modal that i populate with remote content when needed:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="static">
    <div class="modal-dialog"><div class="modal-content">@*-- Content loaded with Ajax --*@</div></div>
</div>
```

and the link i have in the partial view that is rendered after the Ajax Form submit looks like this:

```
<a href="@Url.RouteUrl("ModalUserUpdate_GET", new { id = Model.Id})" data-target="#modal" data-toggle="modal">
    <i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Edit
</a>
```

Is there a bug in the Bootstrap Javascript that is causing this issue or am i missing something?

Any help would be great.

Comment: You have not given enough information to be sure what content your replacing, but if you have attached a plugin to an element that you then replace, you need to reattach the plugin

Comment: @StephenMuecke you are right, there is a plugin for an accordion that seems to be causing the issue. if i disable the plugin then the modals start working again. I will look into reattaching the plugin after the Ajax submit.

Answer (score 0):

@StephenMuecke helped me get the answer I needed. The issue was a plugin that was causing the issue when the Ajax form reloaded part of the screen.